# Cant get return data with cURL in OBJ-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, curl

so im trying to make commands for my iOS tweak! So I think I would be using cURL! and it would be with the GET method.

As an example, if i wrote the command "$ud test" and clicked enter it would return the data from website (https://k8.reko.io/v1/api.php?ud=test) and replace the "$ud test" with the data after i hit send/enter. I have something written out, but I know its wrong. I cant seem to find any tutorials that I can understand online! I should mention that I am a beginner! Thank you!

```
    %hook CoreDataConversationManager

- (void) sendTextMessage:(id)command withRenderInstructionSet:(id)arg1 toConversation:(id)arg2 isSuggestedResponse:(BOOL)arg3
{
   NSString *url = @"https://K8.reko.io/v1/api.php?ud=";
   NSMutableString *userInput = NSMutableString.alloc.init;
   [url appendString:(@"%@", userInput )];

   if ([command hasPrefix:@"$ud"]) command = userInput;
   return %orig;
}
   %end
```

Comment: Wow, I have never seen anyone use `NSMutableString.alloc.init` before!

Comment: :s i had someone help me, but he left, and this wont work ;(

Comment: Study and learn, that is what we did.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this:

NSString *url = @"https://K8.reko.io/v1/api.php?ud=";
   NSMutableString *userInput = NSMutableString.alloc.init;
   [url appendString:(@"%@", userInput )];

you want is something like:

```
NSString *userInput        = @"userInput";

NSString *urlStringPartial = @"https://K8.reko.io/v1/api.php?ud=";
NSString *urlStringFull    = [urlStringPartial stringByAppendingPathComponent:userInput];

NSLog(@"urlStringFull: %@", urlStringFull);
```

> urlStringFull: https:/K8.reko.io/v1/api.php?ud=/userInput